# Variation of Partition of Unity

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

We know as "Partition of unity" that follow:

---

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$.
Let $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots, m$, be open subsets of $X$ whose union contains $K$. Then one
can find functions $\psi_1,\ldots, \psi_m$ such that
$$\psi_i\in C_0^{\infty}(X_i),\quad 0\leq \psi_i\leq 1,\quad i=1,\ldots, m,$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\psi_i\leq 1\quad\mbox{on }X,\quad \sum_{i=1}^m\psi_i = 1\quad \mbox{on a neighbourhood of } K.$$

---

But I want to know if is possible to get a variant where
$$\sum_{i=1}^m(\psi_i)^2 = 1\quad \mbox{on a neighbourhood of } K.$$
I tried to use the traditional Partition of Unity to create $\widetilde{\psi}_i$
such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\widetilde{\psi}_i = 1\quad \mbox{on a neighbourhood of } K,$$
and then define $\psi_i := \sqrt{\widetilde{\psi}_i}$, but the problem is: How I can to verify that $\psi_i\in C_0^{\infty}(X_i)$? Because $\sqrt{\;\;}$  have problems in $x = 0$.

Please, Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ does indeed fail to be differentiable at $0$, since $\psi_i \in C^\infty_0(X_i)$, $\psi_i(x) \to 0$ as $x$ approaches $\partial X_i$ fast enough to eliminate the problem to all orders. Incidentally, are you requiring the $X_i$ to be bounded, or at least the $\psi_i$ (and thus also the $\tilde{\psi}_i$) to have compact support? This is, after all, a huge chunk of what makes partitions of unity useful.

Comment: Yes, they have compact support. For my proffesor, $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the set of all test function with compact support into $\Omega$. Can you please extend your comment as a answer?, because I really want to understand your hints. Thanks

Comment: I'll have to think about it, but now it seems to me you'll actually have to get your hands dirty and look at the explicit construction of a bump function; the point will be, I think, that $\sqrt{e^{-1/t}} = e^{-1/2t}$ has qualitatively exactly the same analytic behaviour as $e^{-1/t}$, so that smoothness will be preserved by taking square roots.